# When error propagation is necessary in modelling?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, linear-model, error-propagation

This is a somewhat philosophical question. When executing classical statistical modeling, such as regression, LM, GLM, mixed modeling, etc., there is often no mention of propagating the error of the dependent variable. The few instances I saw something like that, it is often a relatively simple adjustment, where the standard deviation of the measurement is added as weight in the linear model.

While in some cases this can be cumbersome (some things are expensive to measure multiple times), many variables can be easily measured multiple times. For example, if one doing a classical textbook regression of height vs. weight, it is not hard to take multiple samples from the same subject.

So why error propagation in models is seen so rarely? Is it just a question that errors are assumed to be small enough to be ignored? Or are they already accounted for under the assumptions of normally distributed residuals? Or yet, it is just that this such a complex operation that most statisticians do not bother?

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by "error propagation" in a regression model?  This might be a non-problem.  For instance, ordinary regression $y=X\beta+\epsilon$ already incorporates independent measurement error of the dependent variables within the "error term" $\epsilon.$  There's no separate estimate of error and nothing to "propagate" in any sense I can conceive of.

Comment: For example, imagine the scenario, regressing weight as function of height. One can ask the subject to step in balance multiple times and to measure their weight and one would get slightly different results (due to error in the balance). Hence one can easily get some measure of variation for each sample (say, 72.12 kg, 72.24kg, etc.) Should this error be explicitly incorporated? Should it not? Even if it is non-problem an explanation of why that is the case would be very good, and I would accept as answer. My understanding is that $\epsilon$ takes care of that error, but I'm not sure exactly

Comment: It is already incorporated, as I pointed out.  More explicitly, let $\delta$ be the measurement error and $\epsilon$ be the usual random perturbation of the response: $\delta+\epsilon$ is the actual error in your model.  Without replication you cannot separate $\epsilon$ from $\delta.$ With replication, you can separately estimate them using ANOVA.